# How to convert a sum into binary

Tags: python, algorithm, user-interface, tkinter, binary

My task is to create a GUI program that will allow me to type in my first name and last name. This program is supposed to convert each letter to its corresponding number position in the alphabet, add each together, then convert the sum to binary. I am having trouble starting the algorithm and some help would be appreciated. I have the GUI created, my code is below.

```
import tkinter as tk

numbers = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5,'f':6,'g':7,'h':8, 'i':9, 'j':10,\
           'k':11,'l':12, 'm':13, 'n':14, 'o':15, 'p':16, 'q':17, 'r':18, 's':19,\
           't':20, 'u':21, 'v':22,'w':23, 'x':24, 'y':25, 'z':26,}

class NameGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window = tk.Tk()
        self.top_frame = tk.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.middle_frame = tk.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.name1_frame = tk.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.name2_frame = tk.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.bottom_frame = tk.Frame(self.main_window)

        self.fname_label = tk.Label(self.top_frame, text = 'Enter your first name: ')
        self.fname_entry = tk.Entry(self.top_frame, width = 10)
        self.lname_label = tk.Label(self.middle_frame, text = 'Enter your last name: ')
        self.lname_entry = tk.Entry(self.middle_frame, width = 10)

        self.fname_label.pack(side = 'left')
        self.fname_entry.pack(side = 'left')
        self.lname_label.pack(side = 'left')
        self.lname_entry.pack(side = 'left')

        self.value = tk.StringVar()
        self.dis1_label = tk.Label(self.name1_frame, text = 'First Name and Distance: ')
        self.name1_label = tk.Label(self.name1_frame, textvariable = self.value)
        self.dis2_label = tk.Label(self.name2_frame, text = 'Last Name and Distance: ')
        self.name2_label = tk.Label(self.name2_frame, textvariable = self.value)

        self.dis1_label.pack(side = 'left')
        self.name1_label.pack(side = 'left')
        self.dis2_label.pack(side = 'left')
        self.name2_label.pack(side = 'left')

        self.ok_button = tk.Button(self.bottom_frame, text = 'OK')
        self.quit_button = tk.Button(self.bottom_frame, text = 'QUIT', command = self.main_window.destroy)

        self.ok_button.pack(side = 'left')
        self.quit_button.pack(side = 'left')

        self.top_frame.pack()
        self.middle_frame.pack()
        self.name1_frame.pack()
        self.name2_frame.pack()
        self.bottom_frame.pack()

        tk.mainloop()

name = NameGUI()
```

Comment: The GUI looks fine to me. What do you need help with again? Just the function to add up the corresponding numbers?

Comment: btw, you can use `ord('a')-96` to get your numbers

Comment: Yeah but not just adding up the numbers, also converting it to binary. I always have trouble starting it but once the ball is rolling, I can usually snowball from there but I’m just hitting a block and I’m not sure how to begin.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.  Best of all, each tutorial will teach you a collection of related techniques, rather than merely solving the immediate problem.  As best I can see, the code you posted has little direct value to the problem with which you want help.

Comment: The steps you say are giving you trouble, are each readily researched on line.  Enter those terms into your browser's search window.

Answer (score 1):

1/ "*program is supposed to convert each letter to its corresponding number position in the alphabet, add each together*"
You can use the list properties of string in python to perform that.

```
ListAlphaBet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
Entry = 'example'
number=0
for i in Entry:
    number += ListAlphaBet.index(i)
print(number)
```

2/ "*then convert the sum to binary*"
You can convert any number to a binary in python using the standard type conversion bin()

```
>>> a=5
>>> b=bin(a)
>>> b
'0b101'
```

so to the first previous code, just add this last line:

```
print(bin(number))
```

-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*

To answer your request:

```
import tkinter as tk

def computeEntry():
    inp = entry.get()
    if inp == ' ':
        return 0
    ListAlphaBet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    number=0
    for i in inp:
        number += ListAlphaBet.index(i)
    print(inp,number)
    return number


window = tk.Tk()  # create the window

# next create the var containing the number computed to print it afterward
var=tk.IntVar()
# next create the entry area
entry = tk.Entry(window)
entry.pack()


# the button command will call the set method on the var as a lambda expression,
# with the var value (var.get) that will take the value computed in the function 'computeEntry'
tk.Button(window, text="Compute", command=lambda:var.set(computeEntry())).pack()

# the label's textvariable is set to the value of 'var'
tk.Label(window, textvariable=var).pack()

tk.mainloop() # main loop of the window
```

You now have all the elements answering your questions with full comments, you only have to put this code into object-oriented code if you really want to.

Comment: would you help me plug that into the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

You do actually have two problems:

- Compute binary sum of letters
- Integrate this into your GUI

Sol answered the first problem. Here are some insights for the second one:

```
class NameGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        # Some code
        self.ok_button = tk.Button(self.bottom_frame, text = 'OK', command = self.command_ok)
        # Some more code

    def command_ok(self):
        first_name = self.fname_entry.get()
        last_name = self.lname_entry.get()
        # Do whatever you want
        self.value.set(first_name + "-" + last_name)
```

I do not give an extensive solution, I let you try my code chunk and combine it with sol's answer. In particular, you might want to call his function `computeEntry` once or twice somewhere within `command_ok`. Also, you will probably need to have different variables for `self.name1_label` and `self.name2_label`.